# Listen to other component above

Tags: java, swing, events, listener

Is it possible to add any listener for JButton which should wait for other component above ex. ClickComponent (my own object which I can dragged) ?

```
+------------+
|   BUTTON   |
|    +---------------+
+----| ClickComponent|
     +---------------+
```

I want detect that ClickComponent is dragged above to JButton.

ClickComponent is dragged by left-up corner.

**EDIT**

I try used `DropTarget` but do not detect my component/mouse movement above.

```
for(JButton button : buttonsList){
    new DropTarget(button, new DropTargetAdapter() {
       @Override
       public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
           //log info if drag enter event catch
       }
       @Override
       public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
           // log info if drop event catch
       }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DropTarget dropTarget = new DropTarget(BUTTON, new DropTargetAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
        //do your thing here    
    }
});
```

this should be what you want. its called, once your mouse enters the area with something draggable. replace button with your actual components variable name

Comment: I add it to all buttons but it do not work. Do not catch drag event

Comment: In comment it looked weird.

Comment: thats why you can edit your question. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41180574/edit